# Attaching console to running ASP.NET app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

Let’s say I have a library, in which I added a few `Console.WriteLine(..)` statements to help me out during the implementation and see what’s going on when I use the library in a Console App.

Now I want to use the same library in an ASP.NET app. Ideally I would be able to log on to the production webserver, and somehow start a command prompt and attach it to the website and see the messages in real time as they occur. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it works with ASP.Net, but you can use Trace.WriteLine instead of Console.WriteLine and then use [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) to view the traces as they happen.

Answer (score 2):

You can't - there is not such thing as a console on the server. You need to use [Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx) statements and attach a [TraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx).

You can try [`TextWriterTraceListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener.aspx). `initializeData` is the path to where the log file will be written. *Note: The App Pool Identity user will require write permission to this path.*

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="myListener" 
          type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
          initializeData="TextWriterOutput.log" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```