# Getting Visual Studio's in-built Server to print debugging statements to console?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, iis

For all the benefits of using debugging tools which let you stepthrough the code, view local/global states and contexts, etc., I still find sometimes the easiest way to figure out what's wrong is to sprinkle debug statements through the code and see where something goes wrong first.

Now i'm fiddling with ASP.NET, rather than executing the application, it starts up a web server which i can then access over localhost, and Console.WriteLine() no longer writes stuff to the VS output console when i go to the page. Is there any way to print stuff there? The alternative is write to a log file (i.e. what you do on a real web server anyway) but i'd rather not if i can avoid it. My Googlefu has not brought me any enlightenment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Trace.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.writeline.aspx) will work. You will have to setup a trace listener. Walkthrough on listeners [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y5y10s7.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004853/attaching-console-to-running-asp-net-app) recently, and got the excellent suggestion to use [Trace.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.writeline.aspx) and the [DebugView utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) to intercept the messages. It's quite simple to set up and use.